# Fetch count(distinct value) along with other columns in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, jpql

I am stuck while fetching the count(distinct) values from the databse using JPQL queries. Please refer below query

I have got below table

```
111111      User_A          Dell        Inspiron15      in10
111112      User_A          Dell        Inspiron17      Win10
111113     User_A           Dell        Inspiron16      Win10
222221     User_B           Dell        Inspiron17      Win10
222222     User_B           Dell        Inspiron15      Win10
222223     User_B           Lenovo      Ideapad4        Win10
333331     User_C           Lenovo      Ideapad5        Win10
333332     User_C           Lenovo      Ideapad7        Win10
333333     User_C           Dell        Inspiron16      Win10
444441     User_D           Dell        Inspiron17      Win10
444442     User_D           Lenovo      Ideapad4        Win10
444443     User_D           Lenovo      Ideapad5        Win10
```

using below query I got below output

```
SELECT Laptop_Make, Laptop_Model, Laptop_OS, count(distict ID) as TOTAL group by Laptop_Make, Laptop_Model, Laptop_OS;


Dell            Inspiron15      Win10       2
Dell            Inspiron16      Win10       2
Dell            Inspiron17      Win10       3
Lenovo          Ideapad4        Win10       2
Lenovo          Ideapad5        Win10       2
Lenovo          Ideapad7        Win10       1
```

How can we map the `TOTAL` column to Spring boot `Entity` as this column is not there on physical table with name Laptop and create output table as list of json values

Answer (score 0):

Another option apart from Andronicus' suggestion to use an extra class would be to use `javax.persistence.Tuple` as follows:

```
List<Tuple> resultList = entitityManager
  .createQuery("SELECT Laptop_Make, Laptop_Model, Laptop_OS, count(distict ID)) group by Laptop_Make, Laptop_Model, Laptop_OS", Tuple.class)
  .getResultList(); 
List<JSONObject> allObjects = new ArrayList<>();
for(Tuple result : resultList) {
  JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
  object.put("make", (String) tuple.get(0));
  object.put("model", (String) tuple.get(1));
  object.put("os", (String) tuple.get(2));
  object.put("total", (int) tuple.get(3));
  allObjects.add(object);
}
```

This gives you a list with JSONObjects for each of the grouped database entries.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that OP wants a solution with `JPQL`, the following should do the work

```
public class LaptopAggregation {

  private String laptopMake;
  private String laptopModel;
  private String laptopOS;
  private Long   total;

  public LaptopAggregation(String laptopMake, String laptopModel,
        String laptopOS, Long total) {
    this.laptopMake = laptopMake;
    this.laptopModel = laptopModel;
    this.laptopOS = laptopOS;
    this.total  = total;
  }
}
```

You should already have an entity like the following

```
@Entity
public class Laptop {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String laptopMake;
      
    private String laptopModel;
      
    private String laptopOS;
   
}
```

And you should also by now have a Spring JPA repository like the following

```
public interface LaptopRepository extends JpaRepository<Laptop, Long> {

}
```

Then in the last mentioned repository class you can add the following method and should work as expected

```
   @Query("SELECT " +
           "new com.package.path.to.LaptopAggregation(lp.laptopMake, lp.laptopModel, lp.laptopOs, COUNT(lp.id)) " +
           "FROM Laptop lp " +
           "GROUP BY lp.laptopMake, lp.laptopModel, lp.laptopOS")
    List<LaptopAggregation> findAggregateTotalLaptops();
```